# Copy AWS secrets to another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I have 400 secrets ("Other Type of secrets") stored in account A and need to copy them into account B.

bash script:

> for arn in $output_list;  do   aws secretsmanager get-secret-value
> --secret-id "$arn" >> out.json  done

Now I get an out.json file with 400 secrets.

Having in mind that aws secretsmanager create-secret --name <EXPECTS_A_SECRETS_NAME_HERE> --secret-string file://$out.json

How do I add a function that reads every single secret's block in out.json and creates a secrets in a loop fashion?

Comment: If you are willing to use programmatic access, then use aws sdk to export the secrets and import to another account. What is not working? What are you struggling with?

Comment: So, I'm able to retrieve the secrets and store them into a file. However I'm struggling at using the "aws secretsmanager create-secret" to create all of these 400 secrets automatically.

Comment: syntax  expects you to pass a file, but that file contains 400 secrets. I don't know how to read the file, look for the name, pass the name into a variable and pass it to the command.

Comment: You said programmatically, so I assumed using the aws sdk. You can use aws cli as well. Parse the file, create a secret file for each secret and call the `create-secret` operation. 400 times. I assumed you wanted to import all in a single batch, but I don't see any support for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script like this: `./copy-aws-secrets.sh <source AWS profile> <dest AWS profile>`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source AWS Account details
SOURCE_PROFILE="${1}"
SOURCE_REGION="eu-west-1"

# Destination AWS Account details
DEST_PROFILE="${2}"
DEST_REGION="eu-west-1"

# Array of secrets to copy
SECRETS=(
  "secret1"
  "secret2"
  "secret3"
)

# Loop through the secrets array
for SECRET in "${SECRETS[@]}"; do
  echo "Copying secret: $SECRET"

  # Get the secret value from the source account
  SOURCE_SECRET_VALUE=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
    --secret-id "$SECRET" \
    --profile "$SOURCE_PROFILE" \
    --region "$SOURCE_REGION" \
    --query 'SecretString' \
    --output json \
    --no-paginate
  )

  # Create or update the secret in the destination account
  aws secretsmanager create-secret \
    --name "$SECRET" \
    --secret-string "$SOURCE_SECRET_VALUE" \
    --profile "$DEST_PROFILE" \
    --region "$DEST_REGION" \
    --no-paginate

  echo "Secret copied: $SECRET"
done
```

Comment: I tried using the commands from this script, and it resulted in double-escaping of the values. Changing the `get` to use `--output text` seems to solve it for me - does that sound right?

Comment: @CupawnTae what's your secrets type? I tried it with the `key-value` secret type.